# Merge excel rows based on other column values?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to do the following with VBA or just excels standard merge options if possible:

I have the following 3 columns:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB3yd.png

I what I want to do is to check whether the content of column A and B is identical, then merge both rows into one and comma separate the values in column C:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2mCj.png

How can I do this?

Comment: Best strategy is to try something and, when it doesn't work, analyse why it doesn't. Then try something else. Once you have a pretty clear idea about what's not working, ask your peers to help you with that specific problem, describing your problem and what you've done to solve it so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar a while ago. Here are the steps:

1) formula in column D:

```
= IF (A1=B1, CONCATENATE(C1, ",", C2), "")
```

2) apply a filter on column D for blank cells

3) delete all rows that have blank column D

4) remove filter

5) delete column C

Note: This is only efficient for "one time use" situations. If you need to do this often, developing a macro may be more efficient.